# jOOQ code generation Keys.java member ordering

Tags: code-generation, jooq

For the given jOOQ Maven code generation:

```
<profile>
    <id>code-generation</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${jooq.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <jdbc>
                        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                        <url>${postgres.connection_string}</url>
                        <user>${postgres.user}</user>
                        <password></password>
                    </jdbc>
                    <generator>
                        <name>org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator</name>
                        <database>
                            <name>org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                            <includes>.*</includes>
                            <excludes></excludes>
                            <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
                        </database>
                        <target>
                            <packageName>${packagename_123}</packageName>
                            <directory>src/main/java/</directory>
                        </target>
                    </generator>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

The generated Keys.java generates the following on my local developer machine:

`public static final UniqueKey<BillItemRecord> BILL_ITEM_PKEY = UniqueKeys0.BILL_ITEM_PKEY;`

`public static final UniqueKey<BillingHistoryRecord> BILLING_HISTORY_PKEY = UniqueKeys0.BILLING_HISTORY_PKEY;`

On my CI machine the same Keys.java file has sorted the two lines in the opposite order:

`public static final UniqueKey<BillingHistoryRecord> BILLING_HISTORY_PKEY = UniqueKeys0.BILLING_HISTORY_PKEY;`

`public static final UniqueKey<BillItemRecord> BILL_ITEM_PKEY = UniqueKeys0.BILL_ITEM_PKEY;`

Why are these two lines being sorted differently?

Comment: This is probably a bug. I have created an issue for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5227. The ordering should stay the same for the same schema.

Comment: Can you still reproduce this issue? I suspect this happens when the two databases have different columns in the tables. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @LukasEder I can confirm that the schema is precisely the same on my local and CI machines.

Comment: Hmm, another guess, are the columns defined in the same order on both machines? I.e. will a query against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` yield the same result when ordering by `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION`?